# How do I have an exit pop up go away when clicking anywhere?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, exit

I'm fairly new to javascript and jquery and I wanted to create an exit pop up. I found this very helpful tutorial online but the problem is that you can only exit out of it if you click on the "X" and I want my users to be able to click anywhere outside the div with the content. How do I do this? This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bioep.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            bioEp.init({
                delay: 5,
                showOnDelay: true,
                width: 1170,
                height: 500,
                cookieExp: 30,
            })


        </script>
```

I've linked to jquery and this is the biope.js file I've mentioned previously:

```
    window.bioEp = {
    // Private variables
    bgEl: {},
    popupEl: {},
    closeBtnEl: {},
    shown: false,
    overflowDefault: "visible",
    transformDefault: "",

    // Popup options
    width: 400,
    height: 220,
    html: "",
    css: "",
    fonts: [],
    delay: 5,
    showOnDelay: false,
    cookieExp: 30,

    // Object for handling cookies, taken from QuirksMode
    // http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
    cookieManager: {
        // Create a cookie
        create: function(name, value, days) {
            var expires = "";

            if(days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }

            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        },

        // Get the value of a cookie
        get: function(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(";");

            for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == " ") c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }

            return null;
        },

        // Delete a cookie
        erase: function(name) {
            this.create(name, "", -1);
        }
    },

    // Handle the bioep_shown cookie
    // If present and true, return true
    // If not present or false, create and return false
    checkCookie: function() {
        // Handle cookie reset
        if(this.cookieExp <= 0) {
            this.cookieManager.erase("bioep_shown");
            return false;
        }

        // If cookie is set to true
        if(this.cookieManager.get("bioep_shown") == "true")
            return true;

        // Otherwise, create the cookie and return false
        this.cookieManager.create("bioep_shown", "true", this.cookieExp);

        return false;
    },

    // Add font stylesheets and CSS for the popup
    addCSS: function() {
        // Add font stylesheets
        for(var i = 0; i < this.fonts.length; i++) {
            var font = document.createElement("link");
            font.href = this.fonts[i];
            font.type = "text/css";
            font.rel = "stylesheet";
            document.head.appendChild(font);
        }

        // Base CSS styles for the popup
        var css = document.createTextNode(
            "#bio_ep_bg {display: none; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.3; z-index: 10001;}" +
            "#bio_ep {display: none; position: fixed; width: " + this.width + "px; height: " + this.height + "px; font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; font-size: 16px; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5); z-index: 10002;}" +
            "#bio_ep_close {position: absolute; left: 100%; margin: -8px 0 0 -12px; width: 20px; height: 20px; color: #fff; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #5c5c5c; cursor: pointer;}" +
            this.css
        );

        // Create the style element
        var style = document.createElement("style");
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.appendChild(css);

        // Insert it before other existing style
        // elements so user CSS isn't overwritten
        document.head.insertBefore(style, document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0]);
    },

    // Add the popup to the page
    addPopup: function() {
        // Add the background div
        this.bgEl = document.createElement("div");
        this.bgEl.id = "bio_ep_bg";
        document.body.appendChild(this.bgEl);

        // Add the popup
        if(document.getElementById("bio_ep"))
            this.popupEl = document.getElementById("bio_ep");
        else {
            this.popupEl = document.createElement("div");
            this.popupEl.id = "bio_ep";
            this.popupEl.innerHTML = this.html;
            document.body.appendChild(this.popupEl);
        }

        // Add the close button
        this.closeBtnEl = document.createElement("div");
        this.closeBtnEl.id = "bio_ep_close";
        this.closeBtnEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode("X"));
        this.popupEl.insertBefore(this.closeBtnEl, this.popupEl.firstChild);
    },

    // Show the popup
    showPopup: function() {
        if(this.shown) return;

        this.bgEl.style.display = "block";
        this.popupEl.style.display = "block";

        // Handle scaling
        this.scalePopup();

        // Save body overflow value and hide scrollbars
        this.overflowDefault = document.body.style.overflow;
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

        this.shown = true;
    },

    // Hide the popup
    hidePopup: function() {
        this.bgEl.style.display = "none";
        this.popupEl.style.display = "none";

        // Set body overflow back to default to show scrollbars
        document.body.style.overflow = this.overflowDefault;
    },

    // Handle scaling the popup
    scalePopup: function() {
        var margins = { width: 40, height: 40 };
        var popupSize = { width: bioEp.popupEl.offsetWidth, height: bioEp.popupEl.offsetHeight };
        var windowSize = { width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight };
        var newSize = { width: 0, height: 0 };
        var aspectRatio = popupSize.width / popupSize.height;

        // First go by width, if the popup is larger than the window, scale it
        if(popupSize.width > (windowSize.width - margins.width)) {
            newSize.width = windowSize.width - margins.width;
            newSize.height = newSize.width / aspectRatio;

            // If the height is still too big, scale again
            if(newSize.height > (windowSize.height - margins.height)) {
                newSize.height = windowSize.height - margins.height;
                newSize.width = newSize.height * aspectRatio;
            }
        }

        // If width is fine, check for height
        if(newSize.height === 0) {
            if(popupSize.height > (windowSize.height - margins.height)) {
                newSize.height = windowSize.height - margins.height;
                newSize.width = newSize.height * aspectRatio;
            }
        }

        // Set the scale amount
        var scaleTo = newSize.width / popupSize.width;

        // If the scale ratio is 0 or is going to enlarge (over 1) set it to 1
        if(scaleTo <= 0 || scaleTo > 1) scaleTo = 1;

        // Save current transform style
        if(this.transformDefault === "") 
            this.transformDefault = window.getComputedStyle(this.popupEl, null).getPropertyValue("transform");

        // Apply the scale transformation
        this.popupEl.style.transform = this.transformDefault + " scale(" + scaleTo + ")";
    },

    // Load event listeners for the popup
    loadEvents: function() {
        // Track mouse movements
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            // Get current scroll position
            var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

            if((e.pageY - scroll) < 7)
                bioEp.showPopup();
        });

        // Handle the popup close button
        this.closeBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
            bioEp.hidePopup();
        });

        // Handle window resizing
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            bioEp.scalePopup();
        });
    },

    // Set user defined options for the popup
    setOptions: function(opts) {
        this.width = (typeof opts.width === 'undefined') ? this.width : opts.width;
        this.height = (typeof opts.height === 'undefined') ? this.height : opts.height;
        this.html = (typeof opts.html === 'undefined') ? this.html : opts.html;
        this.css = (typeof opts.css === 'undefined') ? this.css : opts.css;
        this.fonts = (typeof opts.fonts === 'undefined') ? this.fonts : opts.fonts;
        this.delay = (typeof opts.delay === 'undefined') ? this.delay : opts.delay;
        this.showOnDelay = (typeof opts.showOnDelay === 'undefined') ? this.showOnDelay : opts.showOnDelay;
        this.cookieExp = (typeof opts.cookieExp === 'undefined') ? this.cookieExp : opts.cookieExp;
    },

    domReady: function(callback) {
        (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") ? callback() : document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    },

    // Initialize
    init: function(opts) {
        // Once the DOM has fully loaded
        this.domReady(function() {
            // Handle options
            if(typeof opts !== 'undefined')
                bioEp.setOptions(opts);

            // Handle the cookie
            if(bioEp.checkCookie()) return;

            // Add the CSS
            bioEp.addCSS();

            // Add the popup
            bioEp.addPopup();

            // Load events
            setTimeout(function() { 
                bioEp.loadEvents();

                if(bioEp.showOnDelay)
                    bioEp.showPopup();
            }, bioEp.delay * 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the html you're using to render `bioep`.

Comment: Wow ... that is a lot of code you want us to search, to find your problem. Well, I will give you a hint, and ask you to look around this statement: `this.closeBtnEl.addEventListener("click", function(){}` ... which is where the clik-listener is bound to the close-button ... you might want to bind the listener to body, or something else.

Comment: My apologies! I really don't know much about javascript or jquery so I don't even know where to start! But I really appreciate your help and your quick response. I will definitely make those suggestions, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to this is to have an absolute positioned containing div that takes up the entire screen's space, and then have your popup div positioned inside of it. Then if either your exit button or the container div are clicked on you can hide the popup container.

```
<div id="popupContainer">
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="popupExit">
            <p>X</p>
        </div>
        <p>Hello World! I'm a popup!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyb77dbf/2/) of it with the JavaScript and CSS added.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! Since I don't know much about javascript I'm still trying to figure out how to integrate it with the script I already have! Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: It took a little bit of time, but I figured it out! Thank you for your help!